# Query 10 x faster in ASP.NET than in SSMS

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I am currently analyzing the search function of a web application written in ASP.NET / VB. The search function on the home page requests the results from a web service that in turn executes an SQL query and sends back the results.

For analyzing the performance, I debugged the application locally and copied the query to SSMS for running it with SET STATISTICS TIME ON.

When I run the application and check the response time for the requests to my service in the browser's developer tools, they tend to be around 300ms. When I copy the exact same query to SSMS, set all the parameters manually (e.g. "DECLARE @SearchTerm VARCHAR = '%foobar%'"), the query runs for anywhere between 1500ms and 2000ms.

I have found countless mentions of queries running slower from an application, but nothing as to why the opposite might happen.

Has anyone had similar experiences in the past or found a possible explanation for this behavior?

Comment: can you see in the profiler what commands are send to the database before the select is send from the application ?

Comment: Maybe it depends if you are running the store proc or directly the query. Store procedure are compiled and can use different statistic.

Comment: I'm not sure but could be a problem of parameter sniffing, rather than variable can you try putting the  '%foobar%' in your search query and check whether that also takes the same amount of time?

Comment: @SagarShelke That might be the explanation actually. When I run the query with declaring parameters, I get these statistics: CPU time = 2555 ms,  elapsed time = 1742 ms. However when I replace them, entering the '%foobar%' directly, I get this: CPU time = 3746 ms,  elapsed time = 369 ms. Feel free to post as an answer. Any idea why the CPU time actually increases?

Comment: Alter your stored procedure to include the WITH RECOMPILE statement. Also check following article by Kendra Little:  
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/optimize-for-unknown-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/
 and 
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Since this is a search procedure I suspect you are the victim of performance variances in a catch-all query. See this article which explains this phenomenon. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 1):

I have to guess because you have not included the query and its associated query plan. I would guess you are using different values for @SearchTerm (and others) for the query in SSMS versus the ASP page. The query had a query plan optimized for the first time you used it based on the parameters passed in and when you run it from SSMS it uses an inappropriate query plan (for the different paramaters being passed in).

Comment: Google "parameter sniffing" for more details.